# Finding consecutive values within a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary in this form:

```
d = {
  'A': {
     'a1': {3},
     'a2': {2},
     'a3': {1},
   },
  'B': {
     'b1': {1},
   },  
  'C': {
     'c1': {2, 3},
   }
}
```

I have other dictionaries in similar forms as well but my goal is to determine if the numbers `1,2,3` exist WITHIN values of the  keys `A, B, and C`.

In dictionary `d` above the answer is `True` because I have:

`A.a2` contains 2

`B.b1` contains 1

`C.c1` contains 3

So within dictionary `d` I have the values 1,2,3

It is guaranteed that there will be only the 3 keys `A, B, C` and also 3 nested keys `a1, a2, a3` (same for b1, c1). Also, the only possible values in each set are `1,2,3`.

I could iterate all the permutations of the dictionary but i figured that won't be that efficient. Wondering if theres is a smarter way to confirm 1,2,3 exists within the values of `A,B,C`

Here is some sample outputs for other dictionaries:

VALID

- A.a2 -> 2, B.b1 -> 1, C.c1 -> 3

  {
        'A': {
           'a1': {3},
           'a2': {2},
           'a3': {1},
         },
        'B': {
           'b1': {1},
         },
        'C': {
           'c1': {2, 3},
         }
      }

INVALID

- We have B.b1 -> 1, C.c1 -> 2
- We need A.a3 -> 3

OR

STILL INVALID

- We have B.b1 -> 1, C.c1 -> 3
- We need A.a3 -> 2

  {
    'A': {
       'a3': {1},
     },
    'B': {
       'b1': {1},
     },
    'C': {
       'c1': {2, 3},
       'c2': {1}
     }
  }

VALID

- We have B.b1 -> 1, A.a2 -> 2, C.c1 -> 3
- We have 1,2,3 sequence in each first level Key!

  {
    'A': {
       'a2': {2}
     },
    'B': {
       'b1': {1},
     },
    'C': {
       'c1': {2, 3},
     }
  }

Comment: Could you post desired output too?  I get a bit lost in your question.

Comment: if b1 and c1 were empty will the answer still be True since you have `1,2,3` in A ?

Comment: @nfnneil made some updates. Split up the statements so the question is easier to read. Output should be Boolean True or False

Comment: @salparadise No. I am trying to find 1,2,3 in A,B, and C. As in they can occur in any order as long as the sequence 1,2,3 is found in keys A,B,C. So 1,2,3 found only in A while B and C are empty would be `False`. If A has 1, we need B to contain either 2 or 3 and C to container either 2 or 3 to have the sequence 1,2,3 in A,B,C

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far (forming a [mcve]), example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a generator that unravels the nested subdict for A B and C:
It then checks that all the unions between content from A B and C  have at least as many elements as subdicts participating.

```
def unravel_nested(d):
    for v in d.values():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
             yield from v.values()
        else:
             yield v

content = [functools.reduce(set.union, unravel_nested(d[X])) for X in 'ABC']
all(len(functools.reduce(set.union, comb)) >= k for k in range(1,4) for comb in itertools.combinations(content, k))
# True
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it. I know I could remove the dictionary (good), but I think it is good for the sake of learning:

```
d = {
  'A': {
     'a1': [3],
     'a2': [2],
     'a3': [1]
   },
  'B': {
     'b1': [1]
   },  
  'C': {
     'c1': [2, 3]
   }
}

def checkDictionary(di):
    good = {1:False,2:False,3:False}
    for key in di:
        for key2 in di[key]:
            for item in di[key][key2]:
                if item in good:
                    good[item] = True
    return good[1] and good[2] and good[3]

print(checkDictionary(d))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
True if len([i for ind,i in enumerate(sorted([sorted(it.chain.from_iterable([value for key,value in v.iteritems()])) for k,v in d.iteritems()])) if check[ind] in i])==len(check) else False
```

is what you need!

simplifying the list comprehension for better understanding,

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> d
{'A': {'a1': set([3]), 'a3': set([1]), 'a2': set([2])}, 'C': {'c1': set([2, 3])}, 'B': {'b1': set([1])}}

>>> #iterate every key and vaue in dict
>>> [v for k,v in d.iteritems()]
[{'a1': set([3]), 'a3': set([1]), 'a2': set([2])}, {'c1': set([2, 3])}, {'b1': set([1])}]

>>> #iterate through every subdict
>>> [[value for key,value in v.iteritems()] for k,v in d.iteritems()]
[[set([3]), set([1]), set([2])], [set([2, 3])], [set([1])]]

>>> #join list of sets to a single list using itertools chain()
>>> #convert the iterools object to list
>>> [list(it.chain.from_iterable([value for key,value in v.iteritems()])) for k,v in d.iteritems()]
[[3, 1, 2], [2, 3], [1]]

>>> #sort every items in sublist
>>> [sorted(it.chain.from_iterable([value for key,value in v.iteritems()])) for k,v in d.iteritems()]
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [1]]

>>> #sort all items in list
>>> sorted([sorted(it.chain.from_iterable([value for key,value in v.iteritems()])) for k,v in d.iteritems()])
[[1], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3]]

>>> #enumerate and check if each element in check([1,2,3]) is present in each index of obtained list
>>> [i for index,i in enumerate(sorted([sorted(it.chain.from_iterable([value for key,value in v.iteritems()])) for k,v in d.iteritems()])) if check[index] in i]
[[1], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3]]
```

Now compare the len of this result with that of check. If they are equal, then True, otherwise False.

Saying that the following should give the desired result,

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> check = [1, 2, 3]
>>> d={'A': {'a1': set([3]), 'a3': set([1]), 'a2': set([2])}, 'C': {'c1': set([2, 3])}, 'B': {'b1': set([1])}}
>>> True if len([i for ind,i in enumerate(sorted([sorted(it.chain.from_iterable([value for key,value in v.iteritems()])) for k,v in d.iteritems()])) if check[ind] in i])==len(check) else False
True
>>> d={'A': {'a1': set([3]), 'a3': set([1])}, 'C': {'c1': set([1])}, 'B': {'b1': set([1])}}
>>> True if len([i for index,i in enumerate(sorted([sorted(it.chain.from_iterable([value for key,value in v.iteritems()])) for k,v in d.iteritems()])) if check[index] in i])==len(check) else False
False
```